# How to get a image behind text when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I am making a site and I want to have a help button. When it is clicked an image shows up behind the text.

```html
<body>
  <div id="inputdiv">
 Team 1:
<p>
 <input type="text" name="fname" id="name">

<p>
Team 2:
<p>
<input type="text" name="fname2" id="name2">
</div>

<button onclick="showimage"> Help</button>
  <img src="https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg?w=688">
```

How would I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First if you want to call a jquery function you must call as "showimage()" (in your code you should write as

`<button onclick="showimage()"> Help</button>`

And if you want to display image behind the text, set id for that div where you want to show the image and write jquery as

```
function showimage(){
  $("#id-of-that-div").css("background-image", "url('https://support.files.wordpress.com/2009/07/pigeony.jpg?w=688')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first if you are trying to call a function it should be `onclick="showimage()"` not just `onclick="showimage"`

For the picture: 
Try putting the text and picture in the same div maybe? I know that text is defaulted to go over a picture. If not look into some frameworks like foundation